# How would I calculate the probability of poker hands?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

How would I calculate the probability of poker hands?
Basically I do worldbuilding and I figured that the standard deck of cards we use would not be the same in my world. So I made my own deck and now I'm trying to make a poker variant with said deck and have no idea how to calculate the probability of certain hands for said variant.

**What I do so far**

my deck is moderately complex so I'll specify the parts that matter in understandable language.

6 suits and 12 faces mean be like

$1$ $2$ $3$ $4$ $5$ $6$ $7$ $8$ $9$ $A$ $B$ $C$

$1$ $2$ $3$ $4$ $5$ $6$ $7$ $8$ $9$ $A$ $B$ $C$

$1$ $2$ $3$ $4$ $5$ $6$ $7$ $8$ $9$ $A$ $B$ $C$

$1$ $2$ $3$ $4$ $5$ $6$ $7$ $8$ $9$ $A$ $B$ $C$

$1$ $2$ $3$ $4$ $5$ $6$ $7$ $8$ $9$ $A$ $B$ $C$

$1$ $2$ $3$ $4$ $5$ $6$ $7$ $8$ $9$ $A$ $B$ $C$

So we would start by calculating all possible hands right? Which would be 72! But shorter
$72×71×70×69×68= 1,678,985,280$

Then we calculate the amount of hands that contain a pair. This is where I get lostBut after you get that which I'll refer to as X. You just to X/1,678,985,280 for the probability right?

Intuition led me to 72×71×70×69×5 because the first 4 cards don't matter but the last card has to match one of the other 4 which there are only ever 6 of the same and one of them is already in your hand. But this is wrong because you could already have a pair with 72×71×70×69 and thus there maybe less than 5 similar numbers to choose from right?
So I assume that there are no pairs in the first 4 cards giving me 72×66×65×64×5 but this doesn't include 3 of a kind or 4 of a kind etc which technically count as pair hands aswell

Okay I came up with 35.21%

There are 10 possible pair permutations in the 5 card hand, 15 possible suit combinations, and 12 face vales thus giving me 1800 possible pair hands that contain 3 other random cards. So that's 70×69×68×1800 pair hands in total
This is equal to 591,192,000
591,192,000/1,678,985,280=0.3521

**Does this seem correct**

Comment: "*All possible hands?  Which would be 72!*"  No, that is all ways of ordering the entire deck.  "*But shorter $72\times 71\times \cdots \times 68$*" Sure, that is the number of **ordered** hands of five cards, but traditionally we consider two hands the same if they are rearrangements of each other... so better to use binomial coefficients.  "*We calculate the amount of hands that contain a pair... $72\times 71\times 70\times 69\times 5$*"  This is wrong for a few reasons.  Again, order within a hand should not matter and if it did you missed where the repeat did not occur on the last card.

Comment: The first four cards do matter.  You can work out the number of cases with no pair as $72 \times 66 \times 60 \times 54 \times 48$ and subtract that from $72 \times 71 \times 70 \times 69 \times 68$ to give the number with at least a pair.

Comment: The punchline here is that the math involved, approach and techniques, are all identical to the traditional problem using a traditional deck of cards, and this should be covered at length in any introductory textbook and asked here already several times.  Once a suitable duplicate has been found using a traditional deck of cards this will be closed.  The only thing that changes is the specific numbers of $4$ and $13$ will be changed to $6$ and $12$ respectively.

Comment: Have you studied "normal" poker probabilities ? If so, an extension should not be too difficult

Comment: For reference: Probability of a one-pair:  $\dfrac{12\times \binom{6}{2}\times \binom{11}{3}\times 6^3}{\binom{72}{5}}\approx 0.4585$.  Two-pair: $\dfrac{\binom{12}{2}\times \binom{6}{2}^2\times 10\times 6}{\binom{72}{5}}\approx 0.06$.  Probability of a three-of-a-kind: $\dfrac{12\times \binom{6}{3}\times \binom{11}{2}\times 6^2}{\binom{72}{5}}\approx 0.034$.  Probability of a full house: $\dfrac{12\times \binom{6}{3}\times 11\times \binom{6}{2}}{\binom{72}{5}}\approx 0.0028$, 4 of a kind: $\dfrac{12\times\binom{6}{4}\times 11\times 6}{\binom{72}{5}}\approx 0.00085$.

Comment: Really great comments thanks alot to all!!

Comment: @JMoravitz But you may not have realized that 5 of a kind is completely possible with 6 of each number This was the whole reason i needed to calculate this: to know how to rank 5 of a kind and other new hands, of which I do not think exist?

Comment: The comment ran out of room and I never claimed it to be a complete list, but it should be enough to remind you how to finish the rest on your own.  "*And other new hands*" there are no other new hands beyond the five-of-a-kind.  The only remaining hands to consider are five-of-a-kind, straight, flush, straightflush, royalflush, and "highcard"

Comment: @JMoravitz If i did my math correct it would be this:
Pair 45.85%
Two Pair 5.73%
Triplet 3.39%
Full House 0.28%
Quad 0.08%
Straight 0.44%
Flush 0.0339%
Straight Flush 0.000343%

Five of a kind 0.000514%

Comment: This also means you have a lower chance of getting nothing than getting a pair Yeah getting none of these is a 44.08% chance. Which is lower than the probability of a pair.

Comment: @JMoravitz Calculating this more accurately still gives me a lower probability than a pair? So in this ranking it would be Pair, Highcard, Two Pair, Triplet, Straight, Full House, Quad, Flush, Five of a kind, Straight Flush.

Comment: It is whatever you want it to be... but I would advise against treating highcard as more valuable than pair because it is unintuitive and does not match traditional poker.  Conventional strategy in 5-card-draw would be to try to increase the number of copies in your hand of certain ranks to try to get to those rarer 3-of-a-kind and 4-of-a-kind hands and such.  You shouldn't want to be in a position where you have a high-card hand and you have to decide if its better to keep or to risk going for a 3 of a kind knowing that if you get a 2ofakind that it makes your hand worse...